# Amazon RDS and connecting from MySQLWorkbench

Tags: amazon-web-services, mysql-workbench, amazon-rds, telnet

I am struggling with this - i've read loads about it but I still cannot see where I am going wrong.

I've installed MySQLWorkBench and connection tests to my RDS fail.  I've tested using telnet to my endpoints on port 3306 and they cannot connect either.

I've created the classic public/private subnets within the Amazon VPC, this includes a DBServerSG Security Group which is currently set to Allow ALL inbound traffic and allow ALL outbound traffic (for testing) and i've ensure my RDS instance is set with the right DB Subnet Group.

I don't have a firewall on my client PC either

I STILL can't connect to my RDS Instances, any thoughts?

Edit, I created a second instance to rule out password/user problems

Answer (score 0):

### step 1

create a new security rule (or edit an existing one) and add your IP address to gain access to the Amazon Web Service RDS instance.

### setp 2

Go to RDS console > security group screen > select or create a new security group. And add your public IP address (don't forget to add the subnet mask for example /32 after the host).

### step 3

Then figure out what is the instance address, to do so go to the instance menu and write down the endpoint, port number and principal username:

### step 4

now connect to RDS from workbench using a new connection with these Hostname: the endpoint of your RDS instance
Port: the port of your RDS instance
Username: your MySQL username

For further clarification refer to this [link](http://www.inoneo.com/en/blog/10/amazon-aws/remotely-connect-to-an-aws-rds-instance-using-mysql-workbench) for pictorial representation

Comment: Thanks for that, the problem is I can't complete step 1 and I think i've done the others correctly. Specifically RDS Security Groups are disabled: "Your account does not support the EC2-Classic Platform in this region. DB Security Groups are only needed when the EC2-Classic Platform is supported. Instead, use VPC Security Groups to control access to your DB Instances. Go to the EC2 Console to view and manage your VPC Security Groups. For more information, see AWS Documentation on Supported Platforms and Using RDS in VPC."

Comment: It's a classic web( public subnet) and db (private subnet) setup.  I have a web security group and a db security group ...the db security group is the one I have been amending...

Comment: I've also been able to access the RDS from my EC2 instance...which has the webserver security group assigned

Comment: ah, I read something else about ssh-tunneling but had hoped for an easier solution.  Considering that actually uses less changes to security groups (web server already has ssh enabled) - I like the solution.  Amend your answer to include it an i'll give it a tick.  Thanks